# To add a class in codeigniter form

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to add a class in this codeigniter Pls any one help me to solve issue
I want to add this class in this line  class="form-control"

```
<?php echo form_input('username', 'Username'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
echo form_input('username', 'Username',"class='class_name'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs for more info because the answer's there. (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

You can pass `form_input` with an associative array with the attributes you want in it.

```
$attrs = array(
  'name'=>'username',
  'value'=>'Username',
  'class'=>'form-control',
);

echo form_input($attrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   <?php echo form_input('username', 'Username','class="class_name"'); ?>
```

OR

```
$data = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
              'value'       => 'johndoe',
              'maxlength'   => '100',
              'size'        => '50',
              'style'       => 'width:50%',
              'class'       => 'class_name',
            );

echo form_input($data);

// Would produce:

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="class_name" value="johndoe" maxlength="100" size="50" style="width:50%" />
```